# Switch java spring maven project from linux to windows

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to spring development so i am stuck here. Is there any configuration while switching spring + maven project from linux to windows. I am running on tomcat server 7. The project is initially developed in linux. I have moved all the file from linux to wondows. While running on server, i get error The requested resource (/myproject/login/) is not available. Do i need to make any changes or add add in configuation. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell more about error?

Comment: When i enter url same as in linux. i get error message HTTP Status 404 - /myproject/login/ in browser only. But the console has no message at all.

Comment: In your web application's root directory, is there a folder named myproject? If not, then this is what the error is.. If yes, then post the stack trace please for clear error.

Comment: Is the app properly deployed ?. Check the Tomcat logs

Comment: I dont think spring or maven should cause any problem moving from linux to windows, if you have java properly configured on windows it should work on windows too if was working on linux.I think the problem is related to deployment, you can open tomcat manager console and see if the application was deployed check the status of application, see tomcat logs if the application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed something.
Try this.but i'am not sure this is working or not.

Tomcat, by default invoker servlet disabled (commented out in the web.xml file). You have to create a 'servlet' and a 'servlet-mapping' entry in your web.xml.

Once you do, you can get rid of the "servlet/" part of your url.

Check out the following URL for more information regarding the invoker servlet:
http://faq.javaranch.com/view?InvokerServlet

Comment: I do have servlet and servlet-mapping both. But still its not working out.     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>iheat</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Your browser clearly telling your resources not available. so you need to 1. Provide the requested resource 
or 
   2. Request the available resource